# Javascript\Jquery How can i detect if the function is still running? or can i hook in to return event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

So let me describe standard situation: there's a form with multiple inputs (about 60-70). Each inputs needs to be validated. If its not valid it returns false. I need to protect form from `multiclicking(multisubmitting)` to prevent multiple `AJAX` requests with graphical feedback.

My solution is to invoke custom document event before `AJAX` request is sent which instantly creates `div` with width and `height 100%`, `z-index 9998` which contains loading gif and some message. And on completion of `AJAX` request invoke another, which simply removes that element from `DOM`.

**My question is**: is that a valid solution? I mean, its a lot of form inputs and validation may be slower on older computers, which means it can take some time, before shield div is appended to the body and protects form from submitting. Can I simply listen to function and detect whether it returns something or not? In case of deffer my understanding that I need to resolve every time before it returns a value, which means 60-70 new lines of code, which is messy and undesirable.

Is there someone, who faced this problem before and resolve it with 100% accuracy and grace?

Answer (score 4):

Don't rely on a  `"shielding div"` to prevent muliple submits. Just hook into the submit event of the form check before submitting:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    if (!stillValidating())
       //submit form
    else
       //handle however you deem necessary.
});
```

Comment: Thanks, i think it is a valid solution. I end up with turning event off and on wheter validation was complete or not.

Answer (score 0):

you first need to stop default behaviour on form submit then u have to check whether form input is valid  ,  if yes then it goes to ajax call .

```
    $('#form').submit(    function(e){     

        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $(this);

      // check if the input is valid
        if(! $form.valid()) return false;

       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add.php',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                $("#answers").html(response);
            }

        });
    });
```